# How to create a reference to a class field?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, pass-by-reference

My issue is that I would like to create a reference to a class field. (So that I can modify the reference later and have the results show up in the actual class field.)

```
public static Transform operator +(Transform transform, ManipulationInformation manipulationInformation)
{
    // I would like to make this into a reference type.
    Vector3 type;
    switch (manipulationInformation.ManipulationType)
    {
        case "Scale":
            type = transform.lossyScale;
            break;
        case "Rotate":
            type = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            break;
        case "Move":
            type = transform.position;
            break;
    }
    switch (manipulationInformation.Direction)
    {
        case 'x':
            type = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x + manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement, 
                transform.position.y, 
                transform.position.z);
            break;
        case 'y':
            type = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y + manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement,
                transform.position.z);
            break;
        case 'z':
            type = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y,
                transform.position.z + manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement);
            break;
    }
    return transform;
}
```

As with the code above, 'ManipulationInformation' contains three Vector3 fields corresponding to Unity's transform class (of scale, position, and rotation). I would like to be able to add and subtract these (hence the function here is overloading operator+). I would like to make 'type' into something that can hold a reference to one of transform's Vector3s so that I can simplify my code. (A surefire but ugly option would be to put a 'switch(manipulationInformation.Direction)' statement inside each case of the 'switch(manipulationInformation.ManipulationType)' statement; however, the amount of code increases exponentially with more case statements and not very readable.

I am wondering if there is a solution to this madness. Thanks to all in advance!

EDIT: I meant for 'type' to be a reference to one of transform's scale, rotation, and position fields. And make it so that a modification to type would also modify transform's field. However, I now understand that this is not necessary and my issue is due to something else. Thanks Kevin Gosse.

Comment: So every option within `manipulationInformation.ManipulationType` has the three (or more) options `manipulationInformation.Direction`? Than you *have* to do the same thing, however you should consider to plug everything you repeat into a method to reduce code-doubling. Or did I get you whrong, What options do you have when e.g. your `manipulationInformation.ManipulationType` equals `"Scale"`(btw. you´d better be off to use enums instead of strings)? You can scale into x-direction, you can rotate ion x-axis and move into x-direction, don´t you?

Comment: Why set `type` to a value depending on `ManipulationType` only to be overwritten by another switch statement?

Comment: You also seem to be overloading the `+` operator too much. The convention is to use `+` for translation, uniform scaling is performed by `*` between a Vector3 and a scalar, and rotation is performed by `*` between a Vector3 and a matrix.

Comment: Don't understand the purpose behind the code. As for modifying reference, you can always access the Vector3 properties of a transform and assign it a different value. So what's the question? Are you just looking for whether the code can be shortened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are overloading `+` too much. If you don't care about this, then continue reading.

You should probably do something like this:

```
Action<Transform, Vector3> action;
switch (manipulationInformation.ManipulationType)
{
    case "Scale":
        action = (t, v) => t.lossyScale = v;
        break;
    case "Rotate":
        action = (t, v) => t.rotation.eulerAngles = v;
        break;
    case "Move":
        action = (t, v) => t.position = v;
        break;
}

switch (manipulationInformation.Direction)
{
    case 'x':
        action(transform, new Vector3(
            transform.position.x + manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement, 
            transform.position.y, 
            transform.position.z));
        break;
    case 'y':
        action(transform, new Vector3(
            transform.position.x,
            transform.position.y + manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement,
            transform.position.z));
        break;
    case 'z':
        action(transform, new Vector3(
            transform.position.x,
            transform.position.y,
            transform.position.z + manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement));
        break;
}
```

Since `transform` is not a value type, it can be passed around, so you can do this with some delegate magic.

Comment: This is beautiful! I never thought of the possibility of using delegates to overcome this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has two distinct parts: the actual computation, and the assignation. You can make your code much easier to read/maintain by extracting a method:

```
public static Transform operator +(Transform transform, ManipulationInformation manipulationInformation)
{
    var type = ApplyManipulation(manipulationInformation, transform.position);

    switch (manipulationInformation.ManipulationType)
    {
        case "Scale":
            transform.lossyScale = type;
            break;
        case "Rotate":
            transform.eulerAngles = type;
            break;
        case "Move":
            transform.position = type;
            break;
    }

    return transform;
}

private static Vector3 ApplyManipulation(ManipulationInformation manipulationInformation, Vector3 position)
{
    var offset = manipulationInformation.NumericalSign * ModificationIncrement;

    switch (manipulationInformation.Direction)
    {
        case 'x':
            return new Vector3(
                position.x + offset,
                position.y,
                position.z);
        case 'y':
            return new Vector3(
                position.x,
                position.y + offset,
                position.z);
        case 'z':
            return new Vector3(
                position.x,
                position.y,
                position.z + offset);
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown direction: " + manipulationInformation.Direction);
}
```

In fact, the `ApplyManipulation` method should be declared directly in the `ManipulationInformation` class. This is a code smell known as [feature envy](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212128/what-is-a-feature-envy-code-and-why-is-it-considered-a-code-smell). From there, both types could evolve separately and your code would become:

```
public static Transform operator +(Transform transform, ManipulationInformation manipulationInformation)
{
    var type = manipulationInformation.Apply(transform.position, ModificationIncrement);

    switch (manipulationInformation.ManipulationType)
    {
        case "Scale":
            transform.lossyScale = type;
            break;
        case "Rotate":
            transform.eulerAngles = type;
            break;
        case "Move":
            transform.position = type;
            break;
    }

    return transform;
}
```

You could further reduce coupling by introducing a third type that knows how to apply a `ManipulationInformation` on a `Transform` (the whole `switch (manipulationInformation.ManipulationType)` code) but that would probably be overkill at that point.